# yii creating webapp error

Tags: yii, installation

[image: yii create project]

Hi i am trying to create a `yii` application and i am got this issue tried google but not able to find the solution how can i resolve this,..?

```
This is my error:
```

> Error: Unsupported VCS specified. Currently only git and hg supported.

And what actually this error is..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yiic webapp d:\xampp\htdocs` should work.
Notice the backslashes.

Or, perhaps better, since the app generator supports relative paths, navigate to `d:\xampp` and simply run `yiic webapp htdocs`.

That said: why are you using Yii 1 ?

It is really old, and does not receive any updates.

Yii 2 is so much better :)